# How to find a basis for a tricky 2x 2 matrices vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, modules

Consider the vector space of 2 x 2 matrices :\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix} such that a and c are rational  numbers and b is a real  number with rational numbers as the field of this vector space. I need to compute the dimension of this vector space so how can i find a basis for this vector space??.

The issue  finding a basis is basically i: how can i generate the real number entry "b" ?. This is an module theory problem so arguments that goes further than linear algebra are OK. Thanks and sorry for the sloppy gramar :(

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already realized that your basis will include the two vectors
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so our problem is to find a $\Bbb Q$-basis for the space of all matrices of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & r\\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $r\in\Bbb R$. Of course, this is equivalent to finding a basis for $\Bbb R$ as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$. It turns out that $\Bbb R$ is infinite dimensional when considered as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$, which might be part of your problem here. There is a lot written about this. Personally I find [this blog post](http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/the-dimension-of-r-over-q/) a nice place to read about this space.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bro, here is what i got :
I arrive to the fact  that in order to find a Q -basis for
the space of all matrices of the form :
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & r\\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
with r a real number . I can consider the Hamel Basis to generate r  , thus a Q-basis for this vector space would be  :
B^ =\begin{bmatrix}
0 & B\\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
where B is the hamel basis of reals numbers over rationals. And since reals over rationals as a vector space is an infinite dimension space with cardinality equal to aleph 1 then  the cardinality of B is aleph 1 too this way the cardininality of B^ would be aleph 1  so the cardinality of B^^ plus the vectors :
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
is going to be the dimensión  of the original Q - vector space which is  aleph-1 +2 =aleph 1 :)

Comment: Looks like you are the same user who posted the question, but now you have another account. You can get the accounts to be merged by using the [support form](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact).